# Making images stack as the webpage scales down

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get these two images to scale down properly when implementing the media screen query. I want them to stack on top of each other. Here's what I have when I increase the size of the two images it increases on mobile despite the media queries.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <h2 class="templatemo-gold">Our Services</h2>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="stack">
                <img src="images/Page1.png" width="600" height="600" alt="Services">
            </div>
            <div class="stack">
                <img src="images/Page2.png" width="600" height="600" alt="Services">
            </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
.stack {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
  }
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .stack {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This css will give 100% of the browser width to prevent gaps between the divs.

Question: how many images do you wnat side-by-side in each @media?

```
.stack {
  width: 25%; /* because 4 x 100px = 400px */
}
.stack img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* 100% within a div */
  height: auto; /* to prevent distortion of an image */
  margin: auto; /* to center small images */
}
/* lines below are not necessary, removing is no problem */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .stack img {
    max-width: 175px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .stack img {
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the images stacked from the very beginning I decided since it's too small when I do it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Apply your `@media` query to your image directly:

```css
.stack img{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    transition-duration:0.5s;  /* <--- This is not necessary , just to add scale animation */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.stack img {
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.stack img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <h2 class="templatemo-gold">Our Services</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="stack">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/79/536/354" alt="Services">
        </div>
        <div class="stack">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/79/536/354" alt="Services">
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't use a percentage?

Comment: I did what you said and the images are still side by side in mobile and instead of on top of each other. You have any explanation}

Comment: @Sfili_81 I copied the above code, of course using percentage will be better.

Comment: @lebaneseblonde252 could you please upload a screenshot?